# Enable Bottom-Right Numbers in VIM

Tags: macos, vim

I've noticed VIM on my Mac doesn't have the line/column numbers in the bottom-right corner of the window whereas VIM on Ubuntu does.  Is there a profile setting I can use to get my Mac to show these numbers?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try the command "`:set ruler`".

Comment: I also added: set rulerformat=Line:%l,Col:%v to my vimrc file

Answer (score 21):

As [Heptite](https://superuser.com/users/10779/heptite) [described](https://superuser.com/questions/222188/enable-bottom-right-numbers-in-vim/222204#222204), the command `:set ruler` results in the line/column information I was looking for.  If you want to make this behavior permanent, edit your `~/.vimrc` file to include the following line:

```
set ruler
```

Comment: at first I didn't have a `~/.vimrc`, I only had a `~/.viminfo` and I tried to edit that but it silently failed saving my changes.  So I had to create a new file at `~/.vimrc` and it's working great!

Answer (score 1):

You want to configure your statusline in .vimrc, with %l and %c denoting lines and columns, respectively.